# rabbitmq in production php or python

Tags: python, php, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am new to `rabbitmq`. In all tutorials of `rabbitmq` in  python/php says that receiver side

```
php receiver.php
```

or

```
python receiver.py
```

but how can we do this in production?
if we have to run above command in production either we have to use & at last or we have to use *nohup*. Which is not a good idea?

How to implement `rabbitmq` receiver in production server in php/python?

Comment: If you use docker, something like, this might help https://github.com/smartassistco/py-consumer-docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumers/Receivers tend to be managed by a process controller. Either `initd`, `systemd` can work. What I saw used a lot more is something like http://supervisord.org/ or http://godrb.com/ or https://mmonit.com/

In production you ideally want to not only have something that will make sure a process is running, but also that the logs are separated and rolled, that you have some amount of monitoring to make sure a process is not just constantly restarting at boot or otherwise. Those tools are better adapted than running by hand.

Comment: using nginx/apache etc can we do anything?

Comment: Not that I am aware of or could quickly find. But the same thing I said about consumers/receivers, I would also recommend doing with your nginx/apache.